# Moving HTML text next to a button

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm trying to have some text show up next to a button, however the text only shows up underneath the button. Currently, I have in my HTML code:

```
<div class="display: inline;">
    <div class="td-dropdown" dropdown>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" dropdown-toggle>
            Filter Search by:<span class="caret" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a ng-click="dropChange('all')">All</a><li>
            <li><a ng-click="dropChange('floor')">Floor</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="dropChange('building')">Building</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="dropChange('room')">Room</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<a class="display: inline;">{{mockDropVal}}</a>
```

All I want to do is move the text from `{{mockDropVal}}` next to the button. As you can see, I've tried using the `display: inline` class (however i think i am using it incorrectly). As well, I tried to make my own class to do this,  but it was unsuccessful.

Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried actually moving the the `<a>` element so it is next to the button in the HTML. Rather than after a DIV which also contains a list. Put `<a>` straight after `<button>`... then go from there

Comment: What you've meant to put is `style='display:inline;'`! `class='inline'` and then having a class in your css that was `.inline{display:inline;}` would be ok though.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your advice.  I actually took Albzi's advice and that solved my problem!  rookie mistake by me :)  I would mark your comment as having solved my problem,  but I can't seem to do that.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I've written an answer for you @Hyrdopotamus that had my comments in so you can mark that as accepted. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've meant to put is `style='display:inline;'`!

Writing `class='inline'` and then having a class in your css file that was `.inline{display:inline;}` would work the same though.

Having said that, you need to change your markup a little so that the elements will be next to each other. I've moved the `<a>` tag next to the `<button>`, as that's where you want it to be. I've also changed `class=''` to `style=''`.

```
<div style="display: inline;">
  <div class="td-dropdown" dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" dropdown-toggle>
      Filter Search by:<span class="caret" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <a style="display: inline;">{{mockDropVal}}</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a ng-click="dropChange('all')">All</a><li>
      <li><a ng-click="dropChange('floor')">Floor</a></li>
      <li><a ng-click="dropChange('building')">Building</a></li>
      <li><a ng-click="dropChange('room')">Room</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or with the CSS:

```
<div class="inline">
  <div class="td-dropdown" dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" dropdown-toggle>
      Filter Search by:<span class="caret" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="inline">{{mockDropVal}}</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a ng-click="dropChange('all')">All</a><li>
      <li><a ng-click="dropChange('floor')">Floor</a></li>
      <li><a ng-click="dropChange('building')">Building</a></li>
      <li><a ng-click="dropChange('room')">Room</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.inline{display:inline}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have adjusted your code according to your expected output. Do study the changes. Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/peqofetufu/edit?html,css,output) to play with

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.td-dropdown .buttons,
.td-dropdown .dropdownmenu {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdownmenu ul li {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.td-dropdown .buttons {
  vertical-align: top;
  !important
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="td-dropdown" dropdown>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" dropdown-toggle>
          Filter Search by:<span class="caret" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdownmenu">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a ng-click="dropChange('all')">All</a>
            <li>
              <li><a ng-click="dropChange('floor')">Floor</a>
              </li>
              <li><a ng-click="dropChange('building')">Building</a>
              </li>
              <li><a ng-click="dropChange('room')">Room</a>
              </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">{{mockDropVal}}</div>
```